# npm -v Is Different from npm list npm -g

Tags: node.js, npm

This probably comes from lack of understanding on my part but I'm having some weird issues on build machines related to npm.  I ran npm install npm -g in an attempt to fix [this problem](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more).  However, when I run "npm -v", I still get the old version 1.3.2.  If I run "npm list npm -g", I get 1.4.4.

What do I need to do to ensure 1.3.2 doesn't actually exist any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm list -g` will show you the npm modules you have installed, so if npm is listed in there, then you have downloaded npm with npm (yay).

`npm -v` will show you the version of the npm executable you are currently using.

If those two versions are different, then obviously, the `npm` in your PATH does not point to the npm you have installed with npm. On Unix, you can find out with `which npm` where the npm command is located; it’s probably not at the same location as where your installed npm modules go (and as such where the newer npm is located).

Comment: That's the problem.  On other build machines, npm is installed both in Program Files and the local users npm-prefix location with a PATH variable to the latter.  On this one, there is no path variable.  "where" is the Windows equivalent to "which".

Comment: On Windows, you can use `where npm` to get a list of executables. In your case, you will probably want to delete the npm from Program Files (only the `node.exe` should be there), and only use the one in the AppData location.